# Prevent this exception (accessviolationexception in xna) when changing resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I'm drawing a huge amount of lines using xna in my wpf solution. For that, I start this long-term task using this line of code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { RenderGraphics(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

The "RenderGraphics()" method is pretty simple, it's a infinite loop that draws:

```
public void RenderGraphics()
{
    //Loop visual rendering.
    while (RenderGraphicsActive)
    {
        //If RefreshMode is "always" explicity call to method render each time step.
    if (xnaw.RefreshMode == XNAWpf.WPFXNA.eRefreshMode.Always) { xnaw.Render(); }
    }
}
```

RenderGraphicsActive is a flag, and as you can see, this method will stop forever if this flag is ever set on false.

Now is when it gets interesting. In the method xnaw.Render(), I draw a bunch of lines into my "GraphicsDevice" (called "pDevice"), something similar to this:

```
try
{

    lock (pDevice)  //new code actividad 6
    {
        if (pDevice.GraphicsDeviceStatus == GraphicsDeviceStatus.Lost)
            return;

        if (pDevice.GraphicsDeviceStatus == GraphicsDeviceStatus.NotReset)
            return;

        if (pDevice.IsDisposed == true)
            return;

        //...  //a bunch of code

        foreach (Segment segment in Segments)
        {
            mSimpleEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();  //exception here
            pDevice.DrawUserPrimitives < VertexPositionColor(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, segment.VertexData, 0, segment.VertexData.Length - 1); //exception here
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

It works like a charm, but when pDevice changes (for example when I change resolution), it crashes IF the program is already inside the foreach, that's approximately 10% of the times (it usually doesn't crash), but I have to guarantee that it won't crash at all.

Comment: That `catch` did not help?  Have you tried [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Though I would have thought too the `catch` would have been sufficient.  Also any details on exactly what sort of 'crash' it is?

Comment: Nope, that catch did not help. I'm getting a "accessviolationexception". Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.